# How to compare values of a dataframe and apply the condition to the other dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe.

`df`

```
SIN         MOL
339940     250000
322291     250000
321234     850000
```

I want to check the values of MOL are equal or not and display them in the next data frame as

`df1`

```
SIN1                 SIN2       MOL1        MOL2
339940,322291        321234     250000      850000
```

The logic behind this is that the SIN having the same MOL should be joined by ',' in the next dataframe.

Comment: Do you need test `MOL` for consecutive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `join` by `MOL` groups, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), sorting for correct order, convert to DataFrame and transpose, last flatten `MultiIndex` in `map`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('MOL')['SIN'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

df2 = df1.stack().sort_index(level=[1, 0], ascending=[False, True]).to_frame().T
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}{x[0] + 1}')
print (df2)
            SIN1    SIN2    MOL1    MOL2
0  339940,322291  321234  250000  850000
```

Comment: `df3['SIN1']=df2['SIN1']` results to nan. Why is it?

Comment: @AtomStore - What is `df3` ? `NaN` means `df3.index` vs `df2.index` are different.